# Bounded 4-manifold signature

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

My understanding is that the same 3-manifold may have more than one bounded 4-manifold depending on what particular Heegaard decomposition you use to construct your 3-manifold.  I would like to be able to compute the signature of the bounded 4-manifold given any Heegaard decomposition of a 3-manifold.  Is there a method for this?

Comment: If you know the Kirby diagram of the 4 manifold then you can do that.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee OK thanks.  I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @Anubhav Mukherjee I'm really interested in this, can you please point me to a reference?

Comment: @amontillado have a look at Gompf-Stipschiz